# clickhouse schema design, predefined set of columns

Tags: database, clickhouse

I have multiple sources of input with different schemas. To do some analytics using Clickhouse, I though of of 2 approaches to handling the analytic workload, using `join` or `aggregation` operation:

1. Using join involves defining a table corresponding to each input.
2. Using aggregated functions requires a single table, with a predefined set of columns, The number of columns and the type of the columns would be based on my approximations, and may change in the future.

My question is: If I go with the second approach, defining lots of columns let's say hundred of columns. How does it affect the performance, storage cost... etc ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, a large table with all your values + the usage of aggregated functions is often the usecase for which clickhouse was designed.

Various types of Join based queries start being efficient on large datasets, when the queries are distributed between machines. But if you can afford to keep your data on a single SSD RAID, try using a single table and aggregated functions.

Of course, that's generic advice, it really depends on your data.

As far as irregular data goes, depending on how varied it can be, you may want to look into using a dynamic solution (e.g. Spark or Elastic Search) or a database that supports "sparse" columns (e.g. Cassandra or ScyllaDb).

If you want to use Clickhouse for this, look into using arrays and tuples to hold them.

Overall, clickhouse is pretty clever about compressing data, so adding a lot of empty values should be fine (e.g. they won't increase query time by almost anything and they won't occupy extra space). The queries are column-based, so if you don't need a column for a specific query, the performance won't be affected by the simple fact said column exists (e.g. like it would in an RDBMS).

So even if your table has, say 200 columns, as long as your query is only using 2 of those columns, it will be basically as efficient as if the table only had 2 columns. Also, the lower the granularity of a column, the faster the queries on that column (with some caveats). That being said, if you plan to query hundreds of columns in the same query... it's probably going to go fairly slow, but clickhouse is very good at parallelizing work, so if your data is in the lower dozens of Tb (uncompressed), getting a machine with some large SSDs and a 2 Xeons will usually do the trick.

But, again, this all depends heavily on the dataset, you have to explain your data and the types of queries you need in order to get a more meaningful answer.